# Div splitter resize problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a splitter using javascript component, but it works only with two columns, if I add a third column, start to have problems with resizing.

In the excerpt below is where is the logic to resize.

```
var pos = (e.pageX - dragoffset.x);                 

el.style.left = (pos) + "px";

var total_area = $(el).prev().width() + $(el).next().width();

var f_1 = (pos);
var f_2 = (total_area - pos);

$(el).prev().width(f_1);
$(el).next().width(f_2);
```

I have posted my project in https://jsfiddle.net/m4y3rkqc/7/

What parameters should I consider to calculate the size correctly and dynamically?

Comment: Your JS fiddle looks like the columns resize okay, what exactly is the problem (I'm in chrome RN)

Comment: @TimOgilvy
The problem happens when resizing the third column. This spoils the size of the other columns.

Comment: So it does. How are you getting the initial position/width of the third column? it looks like it's getting set to zero immediately that it is clicked.

Comment: Exactly, it seems that the size sets to zero, and then begins calculating as resizes. And it's just that I'm not understanding, since the first column is right.

Comment: I think maybe your first column is positioned right for reasons other than the ones you think it is. The variable dragoffset is always between 20 and 28 when I test it.  That can't be the distance between the edge of the page and the cursor

Comment: You are treating the "splitters" width as dynamic as well as the "panels" width. You should instead treat the rendered splitter divs as having a fixed width and the remaining widths of the combined panels as your "total usable width". So, for example, if you have 2 splitters and 3 panels, and you are shifting splitter "1" to the left, you would then increase the width of panel 2 (the panel to the right of the splitter being moved) and decrease the width of panel "1" (the panel to the left of the splitter being moved), without any need of figuring out the total width at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I identified two problems:

Your second divider likes to "jump" away from you. The reason for that is that you didn't take the size of the element before the divider into account, you can fix this by changing your calculation for `dragoffset` to

```
dragoffset.x = e.pageX - el.offsetLeft 
               + $(el).prev().offset().left - $(el).parent().offset().left;
```

Notice I also added a term to correct for the offset of the parent.

The other thing is that you could move a divider completely to the left or the right of a column and beyond, moving both dividers at half(?) speed while changing the size of all columns and the size of the dividers themselves. To correct this, you need to add 2 checks to make sure `pos` is not out of bounds before further using its value:

```
if (pos < 0) {pos = 0;}
if (pos > total_area) {pos = total_area;}

var f_1 = pos;
var f_2 = (total_area - pos);
```

And here is [**your full code with these changes**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9p4u2h4/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Very good, I could see what was needed to calculate and correct the splitter position. I was not considering the offsets correctly.

Thank you for your response, I hope this helps other users who intend to use splitter in their projects.

Comment: I remodeled my splitter, which I modified the mouse events, leaving all the jquery syntax, I believe the code is cleaner and organized.

The expected result of the splitter remains as the answer given. However identified another situation, when resizing the first time, there is a bug that moves the remaining columns after that it works normally.

updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/pLyqd2vk/

Comment: @Nupi You're right. Something (and it's not your code) is changing the width of every `.panel` if you first move a divider. I suspect it has something to do with `.panel {width:100%;}`. I don't know if this is a real fix or just a hack, but letting javascript determine the initial width of each panel will solve the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/et97gr0y/